# Having trouble setting custom endpoints for Hybridauth provider (WordPress)

Tags: php, hybridauth

I'm trying to use Hybridauth (ver 3) to get a list of an authenticated user's WordPress blogs, using the https://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1.1/me/sites endpoint. Figured out that in order to do so, I need to change the default authorize_url endpoint for WordPress from https://public-api.wordpress.com/oauth2/authenticate to https://public-api.wordpress.com/oauth2/authorize.

Hybridauth lets you change the endpoint, as in this example here: https://github.com/hybridauth/hybridauth/blob/master/examples/example_03.php

Unfortunately, this results in the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to
>   Hybridauth\Adapter\AbstractAdapter::setApiEndpoints() must be an
>   instance of Hybridauth\Data\Collection, array given

The code:

```
$config = [
    "callback"      => APP_URL."/callback", 
    "keys"          => array("id" => "XXXXXX", "secret" => "YYYYYYYYYY"),
    "scope"         => array("global", "auth"),
    "endpoints"     => [
        "authorize_url"    => "https://public-api.wordpress.com/oauth2/authorize",
    ]
];

$adapter = new Hybridauth\Provider\WordPress($config);
```

What am I doing wrong? I feel like I'm missing out on something horribly obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Endpoints should be an instance of [`Hybridauth\Data\Collection`](https://github.com/hybridauth/hybridauth/blob/v3.0.0-rc.6/src/Adapter/AbstractAdapter.php#L320).

You can pass the current endpoints array value to `Hybridauth\Data\Collection` constructor to create an instance and set this to the endpoints key in the config array.

```
<?php

include './vendor/autoload.php';


$endpoints = new Hybridauth\Data\Collection([
    'api_base_url'     => 'https://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1.1/',
    'authorize_url'    => 'https://public-api.wordpress.com/oauth2/authorize',
    'access_token_url' => 'https://public-api.wordpress.com/oauth2/token',
]);

$config = [
    'callback'  => Hybridauth\HttpClient\Util::getCurrentUrl(),
    'keys'      => [ 'id' => 'client-id', 'secret' => 'client-secret' ],
    'endpoints' => $endpoints
];

try {
    $adapter = new Hybridauth\Provider\WordPress( $config );
    $adapter->authenticate();

    $tokens = $adapter->getAccessToken();
    print_r($tokens);

    $userProfile = $adapter->getUserProfile();
    print_r( $userProfile );

    $adapter->disconnect();
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```